# Customize Windows 7 Logon

Tags: c#, windows

How do I program for windows 7 logon screen (not simply subtitude the background image)..Like I want it to authenticate with a RFID reader.Am I able to do that?I know XP could do this.But I found nothing relative to Windows 7 on google.

Comment: Please verify that this is actually a programming question. If the question is really about how to install the right piece of software in order to log on with an RFID reader, then [su] might be a better place to ask this. As it stands, the single answer indicates that this *might* be related to programming. Can you verify what you want done here and edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen OP tagged the question "C#", and the first sentence asks: "How do I program for Windows 7 logon screen ...". I'm not sure what made you think it might be a non-programming question?

Comment: I agree, I have no idea either.

Answer (score 5):

Back in the 2K/XP day this was done by implementing a GINA, but that disappeared with Vista. Now you need to use [Credential Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) instead. [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2006/06/17/82204.aspx) article might get you started in the right direction.